# How and when can we use "why else"?

Tags: meaning, grammar

what kind of Grammer rules is using of " why else" ? when and how we ca use it? and for example, what is the meaning of " why else would you do it" ?

Comment: "Why else would you do it" is another way of writing "why would you do it otherwise".

Comment: *How else, who else, where else*, etc. ***What difference*** does it make?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a question could be asked with a specific answer:

> Q: Why did the ice cream melt?
>   A: Because the sun was hot.

and yet could be answered an additional way, or more information is requested:

> Q: Why *else* did the ice cream melt?
>   A: because I didn't eat it fast enough.

Along with *otherwise*, *else* may be replaced with *also* with similar meaning.

> Why *also* did it happen?

Comment: Though probably the most usual usage is as a rhetorical question, or at least one not _expecting_ a relevant answer: _Of course they was drunk. Why else would they have danced round the fountain in their underwear singing 'Auld Lang Syne'?_

Answer (score 2):

*Else* is a word with rather odd grammar in Modern English. It is an adverb, but it nearly always occurs in three contexts:

1. After a question word (*what*, *who*, *why* etc)
2. In the phrase *or else*, which functions as a conjunction
3. For some speakers, (but not in standard Englishes) as a conjunction by itself.

In all these uses it may be replaced by *otherwise*.

Comment: Also after words that have a prefixed determiner, such as *someone else*, *anything else*, *etc.*

Comment: True. Feel free to edit.